# How to create Dynamic menus in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am developing an website there I need to create dynamic menus like wordpress .but i am new to laravel .before asking question here, followed below tutorial but didn't got how to do?

Refereed:

http://learninglaravel.net/laravel-dynamic-menu-tutorial/link

http://laravel.io/forum/04-16-2014-dynamic-menu-system

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/dynamic-menu

Comment: In your first link OP is explaining how to write a package in L4. L5 has a different structure [tutorial](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/developing-your-packages-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @GordonFreeman.thank you for the link. i will try to understand

Answer (score 2):

Better late then never, but I've just started learning Laravel too. Start with the following basic tutorials. It might be usefull for you or someone else who reads this question.

**Skip the first step** if you just want to integrate your first link into a package right away.

## 1:

First I've just dumped the following in my project folder just to make it work.
NOTE! Read the comments below because there is a typo in the tables "role" and "roles" somewhere. Second of all: if you already have a "users" table by using the "migration" and "seed" files that are present in laravel,
Add a "role_id" field to the "users" table. The tutorial works with the build-in authorization / login from Lavarel. You might want to figure that out first.

https://gist.github.com/drawmyattention/8cb599ee5dc0af5f4246

## 2:

Later on I've followed the following instructions just to make a basic setup for a package:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/developing-your-packages-in-laravel-5

## 3:

If you need any css, javascript or view files copied from your package to your project folder read the following:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages

## 4:

Then at last, try to figure out what your Menu thingie is actualy doing. Take your first link to get some inspitation about how to do stuff.

Do you want to retrieve a list of all controllers and actions that might be menu-items? It's possible but you might have to google it.

And when you add one of those generated list items to a menu: create an action with ajax to add a menu-item to the database.
Get those items from the database in a view-template and create the menu, I guess they use a "facade" class for it but correct me if I am wrong. A facade class can be called like `Menu::create_menu_items();` I am going to try the same thing and realy do it step by step.