# Create a dynamic page using Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I need to create a dynamic html page and menu . I googled but didn't find a good solution for what I need. Any help is appreciated.

Before asking question please refer to the following tutorials:

[Laravel Creating Dynamic Routes to controllers from Mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145245/laravel-creating-dynamic-routes-to-controllers-from-mysql-database)

[Making dynamic pages from DB with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672054/making-dynamic-pages-from-db-with-laravel)

[How to create Dynamic menus in laravel 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758627/how-to-create-dynamic-menus-in-laravel-5-1)

http://laravel.io/forum/06-03-2014-dynamic-pages-and-routes

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Illuminate doesn't ship with Laravel 5.1 but you can do something similar with it.

Also check this out [Laravel 5.1: Class html does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350030/laravel-5-1-class-html-does-not-exist)

Comment: ,my question is to create php page dynamically with html content

Comment: For that you could use Storage::disk('local')->put('file.php', $html_contents). You might also want to track files you create this way in your database in order to dynamically generate the menu.

Comment: @ Oluwafemi Sule,thank you.can you provide sample code ?

Comment: Check this out [link](http://pastie.org/10335359). I include the use of output buffering. With this you're returning already processed output.